# Cannot access my map out of the OnMapReady method

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, geolocation

I've never done anything in Xamarin before and very little in Android at all. I do know C, C++ and some C#.

This isn't Xamarin-forms.

I have searched this for a while and found nothing. More frustrating, I found people that could simply access their google map from other methods when I cannot.

Here, I can access my map, of course. This is of limited interest as I want to interact it after initializing it.

```
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        locationManager = GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;
        MapStyleOptions style;
        string styleString;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("map_style.json")))
            styleString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        style = new MapStyleOptions(styleString);
        googleMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.RotateGesturesEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.TiltGesturesEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.ZoomGesturesEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.ScrollGesturesEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.MapToolbarEnabled = false;
        googleMap.SetMapStyle(style);
        LatLng coords = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        CameraUpdate pos = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(coords, 19, 50, 0));
        googleMap.MoveCamera(pos);
        GMap = googleMap;
    }
```

here I try to access my map by any means possible. The commented stuff doesn't work, I also tried to declare pointers that I would later assign to googlemap within OnMapReady, which wasn't allowed.

```
    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        lat = location.Latitude;
        longi = location.Longitude;
        LatLng coords = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        CameraUpdate pos = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(coords, 19, 50, 0));
        //googleMap.MoveCamera(pos); 
        //FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).???
    }
```

I have seen people just accessing their google map from anywhere.
**All code above is from my main activity.**

I don't know if it's of any importance but here is the entire axml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment  
        android:id="@+id/googlemap"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the big idea is, I'd just like to move the map, whenever the location changes, by doing, in OnLocationchanged, something like

```
googleMap.MoveCamera(pos);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moveCamera can only be called on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the GoogleMap instance in a variable named `GMap` at the end of your `OnMapReady`.

So in your `OnLocationChanged` use that instance:

```
GMap?.MoveCamera(pos);
```

Comment: Oh I did this too. It didn't work either. because I think it's the other google map that's linked to the ... fragment or whatever? I'm not super knowledgeable on either Xamarin or Android. Either way, doing that with GMap didn't work.

Comment: @Tohkai `..didn't work....` What does not work? Is it null, not move the camera, etc...? Exception/Stacktrace/...?

Comment: Nevermind, you're right, I guess GMap /is/ actually a reference to the actual map. I tried doing GMap.MoveCamera(pos) in OnMapReady and it worked, hence, the problem doesn't come from the map, but rather my "OnLocationChanged" method not being called. It seems that I have to look into this instead...

Comment: Re nevermind. As I said, this is probably a copy that's lost upon exiting the scope of OnMapReady. Whenever the moveCamera method is called from outside of it, it just won't work. As in, when moveCamera is called it just never processes, the thread never reaches the line after it. It works however in OnMapReady. So I believe that the right question is the one I asked - how do I affect my map from outside these methods?

Comment: @Tohkai Assuming you have a valid instance of your `GoogleMap`, make sure that you are calling `MoveCamera` on the UI/Main thread (`RunOnUiThread`).

Comment: I just came back to this thread to announce that I found out that the problem was that it wasn't called on the main thread. you are correct